# Entity Metadata Wrapper: Setting User Reference

Tags: 7, users, entities

**Problem**

How do I set a user reference value from the [reference module](https://drupal.org/project/references) using an entity metadata wrapper?

**So Far**

I have a form submit. It's creating an node with a user reference field. I can't work out what structure will submit the value.

First I tried submitting a user account (object), however this throws an awful error.

```
global $user;
$ewrapper->field_user_permission->set($user);
```

I then tried submitting uid, however it said it was expecting an array not a string.

```
$ewrapper->field_user_permission->set($user->uid);
```

I then tried creating a custom array based on printing out the array of a field that was already set.

[image]

```
$user_perm = array (
  'uid'    => $account->uid,
  'access' => TRUE,
);

 $ewrapper->field_user_permission->set($user_perm);
```

But that printed out another horrible error. What should I be using to submit the user reference?

```
 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'uid' for column 'delta' at row 1: INSERT INTO {field_data_field_user_permission} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_user_permission_uid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6), (:db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 246 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 246      [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => contact_details [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => uid [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 182 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 246 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 246 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => contact_details [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => access [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_13] => 1 ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 451 of C:\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).
```

EDIT

New error for creating a new level:

```
$user_perm[] = array (
  'uid'    => $account->uid,
  'access' => TRUE,
);

$ewrapper->field_user_permission->set($user_perm);

PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1: INSERT INTO {field_data_field_user_permission} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_user_permission_uid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6_uid, :db_insert_placeholder_6_access); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 253 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 253 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => contact_details [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6_uid] => 190 [:db_insert_placeholder_6_access] => 1 ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 451 of C:\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working manually without the ewrapper. Using the old school method.

```
$entity->field_user_permission['und']['0']['uid'] = $account->uid;
$entity->field_user_permission['und']['0']['access'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Drupal is trying to set the delta column to the string "uid", which suggests you need another level in your array:

```
$user_perm[] = array (
  'uid'    => $account->uid,
  'access' => TRUE,
);

$ewrapper->field_user_permission->set($user_perm);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that threw another error, I managed to get it working without the entitymetadatawrapper but i can't get it working with it.

Answer (score 0):

To set the initial value or additional values:

```
$ewrapper->field_user_permission[] = $user->uid;
$ewrapper->save();
```

This method also works with wrapped multi value [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) fields.